# Asynchronously load configuration for Sequelize CLI

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am using Sequelize CLI to run migrations against out database and I have the following `.sequelizerc` file

```js
// .sequelizerc
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  "config": path.resolve('src', 'database', 'config.js'),
  "models-path": path.resolve('src', 'models'),
  "seeders-path": path.resolve('src', 'database', 'seeders'),
  "migrations-path": path.resolve('src',  'database', 'migrations'),
};
```

The credentials for our database are kept in a secrets manager so they can be easily rotated and never stored within our repository or someone's computer. Thus, our `config.js` file looks like:

```js
// src/database/config.js
const { AsyncObtainDBCredentials } = require("../utilities");
async function setupDBCreds() {
  const dbConfig = await AsyncObtainDBCredentials();
  return dbConfig;
}
module.export = setupDBCreds(); // exports a promise and does not work
```

Sequelize CLI is expecting a configuration JSON like

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

const dbConfig = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST ?? 'localhost',
    username: process.env.DB_USER ?? 'postgres',
    port: process.env.DB_PORT ?? '5432',
    database: process.env.DB_NAME ?? 'myDBName',
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD ?? 'SuperSecretPasswd',
    dialect: "postgres"
};

module.exports = dbConfig;
```

Is there a way to make this work so we can avoid users having write credentials in to an `.env` file?

Comment: ```module.export = setupDBCreds()```should be ```module.export = setupDBCreds``` and then be awaited in an async setup function.

Comment: The credentials are exported and Sequelize-CLI is the tool that reads them. I would have to fork the repo and add the await myself, as far as I know.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? It looks like I am [hitting the same issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/discussions/17102).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I happened across it while trying to figure out how to pull the connection info out of Secret Manager. I got it to work by doing something like this:

```js
const getSettings = async() => {
  const client = new SecretsManagerClient({
    region: AWS_REGION
  });

  const response = await client.send(
    new GetSecretValueCommand({
      SecretId: AWS_SECRET
    }),
  );
  const settings = JSON.parse(response.SecretString);

  return {
    username: settings.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: settings.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: settings.DATABASE_NAME,
    host: settings.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: settings.DATABASE_PORT,
    dialect: 'postgres',
  };
};

module.exports = async() => ({
  development: {
    // local settings
  },
  production: await getSettings(),
});
```

The key is you can use `async()` in your `module.exports`.